# pandas read text file into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a .txt file

```
[7, 9, 20, 30, 50]  [1-8]
[9, 14, 27, 31, 45]  [2-5]
[7, 10, 22, 27, 38]  [1-7]
```

that I am trying to read into a data frame of two columns using `df = pd.read_fwf(readfile,header=None)`
Instead of two columns it forms a data frame with three columns and sometimes reads each of the first list of numbers into five columns

```
    0              1      2
0   [7, 9, 20, 30, 50]  [1-8]
1   [9, 14, 27, 31, 45] [2-5]
2   [7, 10, 22, 27, 38] [1-7]
```

I do not understand what I am doing wrongly. Could someone please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can exploit the two spaces between the lists

```
pd.read_csv(readfile, sep='\s\s', header=None, engine='python')
```

Out:

```
                     0      1
0   [7, 9, 20, 30, 50]  [1-8]
1  [9, 14, 27, 31, 45]  [2-5]
2  [7, 10, 22, 27, 38]  [1-7]
```

---

[`pd.read_fwf`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html) without an explicit `widths` argument tries to infere the fixed widths. But the length of the first list varies. There is no fixed width to separate each line into two columns.
The `widths` argument is very usefull if your data has no delimiter but fixed number of letters per value. 40 years ago this was a common data format.

```
# data.txt
20200810ITEM02PRICE30COUNT001
20200811ITEM03PRICE31COUNT012
20200812ITEM12PRICE02COUNT107
```

[`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) `sep` argument accepts multi char and regex delimiter. Often this is more flexible to separate strings to columns.

Comment: Might I prevail upon you to explain why this makes the difference. It has certainly solved the problem

Comment: Added a short explanation.

Comment: Very useful. Thank you. I guess that using read_csv has the added benefit that empty lines can be ignored which does not work with read_fwf

Answer (score 0):

By single line you can read using pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(readfile, sep='\s\s')
```